# knockout: displaying array categories in columns

Tags: knockout.js

I've taken a basic example on templates from the knockoutjs website. I'm using this for learning purposes but I need to apply it to an existing project. Here is a basic fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hRm22/ The array is as follows:

```
var viewModel = {
    seasons: ko.observableArray([{
        name: 'Spring',
        months: ['March', 'April', 'May']
    }, {
        name: 'Summer',
        months: ['June', 'July', 'August']
    }, {
        name: 'Autumn',
        months: ['September', 'October', 'November']
    }, {
        name: 'Winter',
        months: ['December', 'January', 'February']
    }])
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

What I would like to do is to display the seasons column by column, ie. column headers: Spring, Summer, Autumn, Winter; then the individual months according to their respective columns. It seems fairly simple but I can't quite get it in that format.

Should I carry on using tables or would it be best to use divs instead?

Comment: I managed to get this working with tables by modifying @Wayne's fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/94hpU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier if you do it without tables. There isn't really a need to use a template here. You could make it a template though.

```
<!-- ko foreach: seasons -->
<ul class="column">
    <li data-bind="text: name" class="header"></li>
    <!-- ko foreach: months -->
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->

.column {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header {
    font-weight: bold
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/94hpU/

Comment: This is pretty neat! However I needed to use tables because in my project, I have a long list of questions which I'm displaying in a data-bind="foreach..", but when tabulating the scores, I need to place each question in their appropriate column (ie. Q7, 8, 10, 11 in Column 1; Question 22, 23, 24, 27 in column 4 etc.). I'm not sure if I can do it without a table...

Comment: Anyway, now that you have given me the concept of how to do it, I think I have an idea on how to apply it to my table. Thanks a ton Wayne! :)

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I got it working with the tables. Updated the question with edited fiddle.